# How to run Drupal.ajax commands on initial form load?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I've created some custom Drupal.ajax commands.

And I have ajax callbacks working as fields change value.

But I'd like to run some of these ajax commands on initial form load.

My use case: I have values set on drop downs, depending on the drop downs I want to call some js with a settings array to display custom information on a map, set up call backs etc.

Is there a clean way of doing this? Having a consistent method for the initial set up and the ajax call backs is what i'm after i guess.

Or should I use just use `drupal_add_js($js, array('type' => 'inline'));` in my form builder?

To expand a little, in the ajax function I have access to a flexible array of commands I can send back to client:

```
function agc_ems_form_letterdrop_change($form, &$form_state) {                     
  $commands = array();                                                             
  $values = Agc::hasValue($form_state, 'values');                                  
  $letterdrop_id = Agc::hasValue($values, 'letterdrop_id');                        
  if ($letterdrop_id) {                                                            
    $letterdrop = new AgcLetterDrop($letterdrop_id);                               
    // add command to zoom to bounds                                               
    $bounds = $letterdrop->bounds(array(                                           
          'margin' => -0.2,                                                        
          'as_string' => FALSE,                                                    
          ));                                                                      
    // uses custom commands defined in agc.map.js                                  
    $commands[] = array(                                                           
        'command' => 'agcZoom',                                                    
        'bounds' => $bounds,                                                       
        );                                                                         
    $commands[] = array(                                                           
        'command' => 'agcNewDrop',                                                 
        'id' => $letterdrop_id,                                                    
        'label' => $letterdrop->title(),                                           
        );                                                                         
    // add commands to addlayers                                                   
    $layers = $letterdrop->mapLayers(array(                                        
          //fixme should be from form_state                                        
          'mapobj' => 'Agcj.map.formmap',                                          
          'ldaMode' => "lda_allocate",                                             
          ));                                                                      

    $allocation_sql = $letterdrop->sql(array(                                      
          'mode' => 'slot',                                                        
          'drop_id' => $letterdrop_id,                                             
          ));                                                                      
    $commands[] = ajax_command_settings(array(                                     
          'letterdrop_allocations' => array(                                       
            'id' => $letterdrop_id,                                                
            'slots' => AgcDb::sqlTo2dArray($allocation_sql),                       
            'msg' => array('new allocations from ajax handler'),                   
            )));                                                                   

    $commands[] =                                                                  
      ajax_command_replace("#agc_letterdrop", render($form['ld']));                
  }                                                                                
  else {                                                                           
    $commands[] = ajax_command_alert('No letterdrops selected');                   
  }                                                                                

  return array(                                                                    
      '#type' => 'ajax',                                                           
      '#commands' => $commands);                                                   
}
```

but I cant do that in my form builder for my initial form load.

instead I do something like this:

```
 $all_letterdrop_allocations = array(
     'msg' => array('new allocations from form builder'),                  
     'id' => $letterdrop_id,
     'slots' => AgcDb::sqlTo2dArray($allocation_sql),                      
     );
 drupal_add_js(array(                                                      
       'letterdrop_allocations' => $all_letterdrop_allocations),           
     'setting');
 drupal_add_js('alert("hello");', 'inline');
```

so it just seems a bit inconsistent...

i guess this is bit backwards - because I wanted to get the ajax behaviours working (mission accomplished) but now I'm want to get a nice form bootstrap happening but finding I need to repackage my logic...

so is there a better way to do both phases consistently?

Comment: Hello and welcome :) Can we assume you have read [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722), especially [behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) section? Have you tried behavior? If so, then yes, that's the right way, but show us your code.

Comment: ta @Mołot, expanded my Q :-)